# Variable Not Changing

Tags: vba

I am programming with VBA in PowerPoint 2016. I want a variable (`Var1`) to increment when a button is clicked. It should increment by the amount of `Var2`. This is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub MyButton_Click()
Var1 = Var1 + Var2
End Sub
```

However, when I add `MsgBox(Var1)` to the end of the sub, it will display the value of the variable before the increment was applied.

All variables are declared at the top of a module like this: `Public [VariableName] As Integer`. The value of Var2 is set on the previous slide like this:

```
Private Sub MyOtherButton_Click()
If 'number is in my specified range then
    Var2 = MyTextBox.Value
Else
    MsgBox("Enter a value between min and max")
End If
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: how and where are the variables declared?

Comment: All of the variables are declared at the top of a module using the `Public` keyword: e.g. `Public Var1 As Integer`

Comment: maybe `Var2` = 0?

Comment: Where do you set the value of var2?

Comment: @ScottCraner, check the edit that will be saved soon.

Comment: you are not setting a value to var2 in the else.  so it may be `0`

Comment: @ScottCraner, I saved the edit.

Comment: @ScottCraner, Yes, but I make sure that during my testing I always input a value in the specified range. I'll add more preventative measure later.

Comment: stop the code at the `Var1 = Var1 + Var2` and make sure Var2 has a value.

Comment: I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I only *thought* that the variables were being declared correctly. I had to declare them in the *module*, not the code for the "Slide#" object.